# Flutter: get state from StatefulWidget?

Tags: flutter, state

Is there a way to get the state from a StatefulWidget?

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}
```

From widget inspector detail, the statefulWidget has a member variable "state". But could not access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a widget's state from somewhere else you could give the widget a `GlobalKey` and then access the state through `currentState` of that key. Here's an example of how to do it:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  GlobalKey<CounterState> counterKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: [
        Counter(key: counterKey),
        TextButton(
            onPressed: () => counterKey.currentState?.increaseCounter(),
            child: const Text('Increase'))
      ]),
    );
  }
}

class Counter extends StatefulWidget {
  const Counter({super.key});

  @override
  State<Counter> createState() => CounterState();
}

class CounterState extends State<Counter> {
  int counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(counter.toString());
  }

  void increaseCounter() {
    setState(() {
      counter++;
    });
  }
}
```

As you can see we are creating a `GlobalKey` for the `Counter` widget and then in the `TextButton` we can access that same key and get the state with `currentState` and then use methods of that state like `increaseCounter` in this example.

Comment: Can GlobalKey be given a unique id? can it be reconstructed? e.g., GlableKey("id1").currentState. The Id is from server side, which specifies which widget to rebuild.

Comment: You could put the keys in a Map maybe